# Relationship between Km and IC50 in cellular uptake assay

Tags: enzyme-kinetics, membrane-transport

I'm going to describe the scenario in general terms at first so as to try and get to the theoretical content of the problem, but I'll post a link to the paper which got me thinking about it at the bottom of the post.

The setup for the assay is as follows. There is a membrane transport protein $P$ which can transport multiple substrates, of which we'll focus only on two, call them $S_1$ and $S_2$. To measure transport via $P$, we have a radiolabeled version of $S_1$ which I'll label as $S^{rad}_1$. The assay protocol is to first incubate cells overexpressing $P$ with a mixture of $S_1$ and $S^{rad}_1$ as well as other molecules of interest, wash off any remaining radioactive substrate which has not been taken up, dissolve the cells, and measure the resulting radioactivity in each condition. We can directly observe the $K_m$ for $S_1$ by measuring the initial rates at which $P$ transports $S_1$ at varying concentrations of $S_1$. We'll further assume that the ratio of $S_1$ and $S^{rad}_1$ is constant. Because $S_1$ and $S_2$ can both be transported by $P$ (assume via identical mechanisms), $S_2$ will act as a competitive inhibitor to the transport of $S_1$ if we add it into the incubation solution during the assay. If we keep $S_1$ and $S^{rad}_1$ constant and then vary the concentration of $S_2$, we'll observe less uptake of $S^{rad}_1$ as $[S_2]$ increases due to $S_2$ out-competing the former. We can then get an $IC_{50}$ value for $S_2$ with regards to the transport of $S_1$. My question, then, is: **how does the $IC_{50}$ of $S_2$ when it is inhibiting the transport of $S_1$ relate to the $K_m$ of $S_2$ when it is being transported by $P$?** Does there even exist such a relationship or would we have to use a radiolabeled version of $S_2$ to observe any data about its $K_m$?

I believe this is an accurate generalized description of the scenario at hand, but please point out/correct any mistakes I have made! As I mentioned, this scenario was inspired by a published journal paper which you can find here:

https://jpet.aspetjournals.org/content/295/1/392.long

In this paper, succinate acts as $S_1$ and N-Acetylaspartate, aspartate, and glutamate independently take on the role of $S_2$. In Fig. 2, the authors provide inhibition curves for succinate transport as the concentration of NAA, aspartate, and glutamate vary. They are able to fit this data to get $IC_{50}$ values for the three molecules, but they then, in the abstract, extrapolate these $IC_{50}$ values to be identical to the Michaelis-Menten constants for the substrates. This is the primary source of my confusion, as intuitively I don't feel that it is a valid assumption that $K_m = IC_{50}$ when the competitive 'inhibitor' can also act as a substrate for the transport protein. However, I haven't been able to find any information about this topic online and it's certainly not my strength as a new researcher hence my asking here instead.

Thank you for reading and for any help you are able to provide!

Comment: Another clue that something is going awry here is that I don't believe the paper (or my generalized scenario) assume anything about how the 'inhibitors' interact with the protein. That is to say, even though the authors show that NAA does get transported, their fitting of the $IC_{50}$ and then extrapolating this to the Michaelis-Menten constant does not make any assumptions about the fate of the 'inhibitor'. Obviously, a competitive inhibitor which lodges itself in the active site and prevents transport has no $K_m$ yet you could apparently claim its $IC_{50}$ as such.